# Apple Wallet Press (i) on card

Tags: passbook, wallet

Have you idea how to make "Press (i)" on card?

[image: example]

There are no information in the documentation.

Comment: You simply add the Unicode character `U+1F6C`

Comment: Thanks for idea. But U+1F6C is OMEGA. What is correct code? And is it possible to make this label clickable to flip card?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, was searching on my phone and copied the wrong code.  Clickable is impossible for any front fields.  Maybe this can help you find the correct code http://wt.is/91

Comment: Thank you! Unicode for (i) is U+24D8